# Java 2D tile map and rendering it

Tags: java, maps, terrain-rendering

Please help me! I am thinking of generating different terrains environment every time the game loads again. But i am thinking of loading or drawing a image containing all the units like river, land and tree. Then the checking of obstacles against the units like boat, car and plane. I have done lots of research but i am struck on how to do it. Please help me.

Comment: What you've described could be literally anything in a game. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Check out the [FAQ] for some discussion oriented sites. Where to get started questions should be asked there.

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit general so here's a general answer. http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/TiledMaps gives a tutorial on using a tilemap (http://www.mapeditor.org/) within your game. You can dynamically change tiles, etc. Each tile may have properties, such as which objects are stored within it, or whether it is water (in which case you'd only let a player swim or use a boat, but not drive a car) or whether it's a tree (in which case you can't walk through it) etc. If you want a more specific answer you'll have to provide a more specific question.